# Automatic line break in Java html text editor

Tags: java, html, line-breaks, jtextpane

I am creating a text editor in java that saves the text as html, but displays as plain text to the user. The user has the ability to change the color, alignment and style (bold and underline) of the text. The entire body of text is stored in the database as html in order to save the style adjustments. I am having an issue with newlines not being saved. So when the user is entering text, presses enter and puts text on a new line, it all gets put on one line after be saved and re-displayed. All the text is just being put inside on paragraph tag without any line breaks. I'm wondering if there's a way to tell the text editor to automatically insert line breaks for new lines?

The way I have my editor set up is a JTextPane using a HTMLEditorKit with content type set to text/html. I am using StyledEditorKit actions for changing the color and style (bold, underline) of the text and StyleConstants.setAlignment for changing the text alignment (I had some issues with the StyledEditorKit.AlignmentAction). Let me know if you need any specific source code.

Comment: Have you tried what happens on "Ctrl-Enter"? I can remember darkly something with this and linebreaks in JTextPane ...

Answer (score 0):

try encapsulating your text inside an html < p > tag - it should maintain line breaks.

Comment: Didn't he already state that this is _not_ the case? "All the text is just being put inside on paragraph tag without any line breaks."

Comment: It appears that it IS putting the paragraph tags in certain situations. But in other situations, it is not. If I enter text and with a new line, it does not put it in <p> tags. But if I enter the same text and choose an alignment, it does use <p> tags. But instead of using line breaks, it puts the different lines in separate <p> tags, which does cause the lines to be on separate lines as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a key down event for this kit?  Assuming you have a KeyEvent handler you should be able to do something like this:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER){
editor.Text += "<br />"; 
}
```

Comment: That would always _append_ a new line at the end, not dependend on the cursor position.

Comment: Good point!  But hopefully he could get the cursor positions inside the editor and insert the text there.

Comment: definitely something to try. how would this work if the user wants to later get rid of the new line? like they hit enter then backspace up to the original line.

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure how your editor work or the most scientific way to do it but maybe: if(key.backspace && textField.getText().substring(cursorPos-6, 6).equals("<br />")) { //remove 6 characters from your html side }  I will note this could cause performance issues.